# Converting between tree types (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, tree, type-conversion

Goodday,

For a school assignment, I have to write a very simple program; I need to convert trees from one type to another. But I'm stumped, because I could not attend the lectures and thus have no idea what is wrong with my code. The assignment is to convert trees from type Tree1a to RoseTree:

```
data RoseTree = RoseNode String [RoseTree]
data Tree1a = Leaf1a Number | Node1a Number Tree1a Tree1a

tree = Node1a 1 (Leaf1a 2)
                (Node1a 3 (Leaf1a 4)
                          (Leaf1a 5))

pp1a :: Tree1a -> RoseTree
pp1a (Leaf1a n)            = RoseNode (show n) []
pp1a (Node1a n left right) = RoseNode (show n) [pp1a left, pp1a right]
```

(Number is defined in a library that was given by the teacher, but that is not the issue here.) But this does not work; when I run showTree (pp1a tree) nothing happens, it just runs forever (showTree is a print function defined for RoseTree in some library given by the teacher).

Comment: Your error must be somewhere else. The test tree that's given should not cause an infinite recursion (nor should any other finite tree).

Answer (score 1):

The error was not in the code; the error was in me not recognising exactly what the showTree function did, which was not printing to the console (as I had expected).

Answer (score 0):

I added `deriving Show` to the `RoseTree` type signature and it worked for me.

```
*Main> pp1a tree
RoseNode "1" [RoseNode "2" [],RoseNode "3" [RoseNode "4" [],RoseNode "5" []]]
```

Although I did change `Number` to `Int`, but I can't see this making much difference!

Comment: Hm, it appears that it worked after all. The reason I thought something went wrong was because nothing happened in the console window, but what it did (although I don't know how yet) is show the data graphically in a html file via some scripting. Thanks for the fast commenting and testing though!

Comment: @user3316806: If you managed to fix the problem yourself, add an answer.